# JQuery set input box value to this.value onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#something1").click(function(){
        $("#something2").val(this.val);
});
```

I'm trying to set the value of something2 to the value of something1 onclick ...

Comment: Seems like that code should work if you used `this.value` which is the DOM way to reference the value like you mentioned in the title of the question.

Comment: `this.value` or `$(this).val()`.

Comment: **It's funny**. _set input box value to this.value onclick?_ in the title, so you know that you should use `this.value` and still used `this.val` in code.

Comment: @Tushar Haha I didn't notice that.  :) :D

Answer (score 1):

`this.value` not `this.val`

```
$("#something1").click(function(){
   $("#something2").val(this.value);
});
```

`this.val` will be evaluated to `undefined`. And it will be passed into the `.val()` function. Eventually it will be ignored.

Technically, in the `.val()`'s function definition, the logic would be, if it was called without any parameter, then the `value` of the current element over which the `.val()` was called will be returned.

calling `$("#something2").val(undefined)` will be similar to `$("#something2").val()`

Answer (score 0):

Or use the jQuery *val* function:

```
    $("#x").click(function(){
        $("#y").val($(this).val());
    });
```